# Python with XLSXWRITER: spreadsheet overwritten

Tags: python, overwrite, xlsxwriter

This is the basic flow that my Python script is following with XLSXwriter:

1. Create Workbook
2. Create Worksheet
3. Define Formatting
4. Write Column Headers in row1 (leveraging formatting from Step3)
5. Write Actual Data in subsequent rows (no special formatting)

I can create the workbook/worksheet.  I then define formatting and populate worksheet row1 columns A:H with 'COLUMN HEADERS' which signify the type of DATA that will be written into each column on subsequent rows.  This much is a success.

My code and problem description are below:

```
# write column header information
if total_xls_records == 1:
    worksheet1.set_row(0, 15, header_format)
    worksheet1.set_column('A:H',30)
    worksheet1.write('A1', 'Hostname')
    worksheet1.write('B1', 'Serial')
    worksheet1.write('C1', 'Manufacturer')
    worksheet1.write('D1', 'Model')
    worksheet1.write('E1', 'RAM')
    worksheet1.write('F1', 'Flash')
    worksheet1.write('G1', 'Version')
    worksheet1.write('H1', 'SW_Image')
# write device data to spreadsheet
else:
    worksheet1.set_row(total_xls_records, 15)
    worksheet1.set_column('A:H',30)
    worksheet1.write('A2', data[0])
    worksheet1.write('B2', data[1])
    worksheet1.write('C2', data[2])
    worksheet1.write('D2', data[3])
    worksheet1.write('E2', data[4])
    worksheet1.write('F2', data[5])
    worksheet1.write('G2', data[6])
    worksheet1.write('H2', data[7])
```

I'm pulling data in from a list to populate my cells.  The result of this if/else is:

1. When I match the "if" statement, the column headers get written to spreadsheet properly

If I open the spreadsheet, I see row1 columns A:H properly populated and formatted per header_format with a column width of 30.

2. When I subsequently match the "else" statement, the spreadsheet is overwritten

If I open the spreadsheet, I see row1 is completely empty (all column headers/formatting are now gone) and row2 is properly populated with device DATA (no formatting).

Obviously the desired behavior is to have row1 with COLUMN HEADERS and rows2-whatever with DATA.  I want to 'append' DATA to the spreadsheet in rows2-whatever AFTER row1 has already been written.

Yes, I'm aware that the else statement currently calls a 'static list' of cells (A2-H2) and that this means multiple matches of else will currently write DATA into the same set of cells.  It's currently written this way because I'm in 'troubleshooting mode' for the problem I just described.  For me it makes sense to fix the spreadsheet overwrite problem before re-writing my "cell population" code.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: So I've solved my own problem and am posting this comment in case it will help someone else.  It looks like XLSXWRITER writes a spreadsheet 'all at one time'.  Once the initial write operation completes, the file is essentially 'closed for business'.  Once that happens, any subsequent write attempts seem to overwrite the file.  So my solution was instead of having an if/else loop, to use a for loop to iterate through a 'list of lists'.  I used 'for item in list' followed by 'for item in item' to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XlsxWriter cannot rewrite a file or repeatedly save to a file.

Once `workbook.close()` is called the file is written and closed.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured.  Dunno if XLSXwriter is still under development or taking features requests but multi-write and read would be awesome.  I looked at several python modules for writing spreadsheets... XLSXwriter had great documentation, was simple to understand, and I had it working right away.  Would love to see this module developed further.

Comment: XlsxWriter is still under development and new features are rolled out periodically. However there are no plans to add reading/rewriting functionality. That is just too big a task.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the straight answer.  :)

Comment: @jmcnamara. Hi. I presume your previous comment regarding reading/rewriting still holds? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. That is still the case for now and the future.